# Error Running Android When Change Background

Tags: android, xml

I have file bacground_im.png at drawable.
when I change background at Activity_main.xml I got error.

How to resolve problem?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/background_im">
```

Comment: change it to what? and what is the error

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps 
 you can also set  background in code 
first add LinearLayout id as in your layout xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/linearLayoutid"
 android:minWidth="25px"
 android:minHeight="25px"
 android:background="@drawable/
background_im"
```

and in code part set background as::

```
   LinearLayout linearLayout =
 (LinearLayout)
 findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutid);
 linearLayout.setBackgroundResource
(R.drawable.background_im);
```